# Spring form:options is extremely slow in jsp

Tags: spring, performance, jsp, spring-mvc

I have this slow code in my jsp:

```
<form:options itemLabel="name" itemValue="id" items="${view.users}"  />
```

And when I just replace it with

```
<c:forEach items="${view.users}" var="user">
            <form:option value="${user.id}">${user.name}                    
            </form:option>
</c:forEach>
```

There is big impact on the performance. I just can understand why? Does this is because of **view.users** collection of complex objects?

Comment: I guess there are some type conversions happening internally when we use `<form>` tag. If you are not performing complex logic in the `forEach` loop, consider using the basic `<option>` HTML tag.

Comment: There is no complex logic just iteration.

Comment: **What** is slow? Creating the response, displaying HTML ...?

Comment: Displaying HTML is slow, when I have a lot of elements in the collection and my automation tests fails.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the `Spring` [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-optionstag) for the `<options>` tag,

> The combined usage of an option tag with the options tag generates the same standard HTML, but allows you to explicitly specify a value in the JSP that is for display only (where it belongs) such as the default string in the example: "-- Please Select".
>
> The items attribute is typically populated with a collection or array of item objects. itemValue and itemLabel simply refer to bean properties of those item objects, if specified; otherwise, the item objects themselves will be stringified. Alternatively, you may specify a Map of items, in which case the map keys are interpreted as option values and the map values correspond to option labels. If itemValue and/or itemLabel happen to be specified as well, the item value property will apply to the map key and the item label property will apply to the map value.

Here, `Spring` is checking for bean properties and before rendering to the actual HTML the type conversions are done. So, this makes a lot of background work to provide the clean code for the developers (which comes at the price of performance).

So, if there is no specific requirement/logic to display the options, prefer the basic HTML `<option>` tag.